# Incremental delay in reading from serial com port

Tags: c#, wpf, serial-port

I am building a WPF application that reads from two serial ports simultaneously. The device on one port (weighing machine) is sending a 7 character string every second. The devices on second port (Milk analyzer machine) sends a 275 character string on a manual button press on machine.

I am using following code to configure and open ports on startup:

```
//serial port for Milk Machine
serialPortMilk = new SerialPort
            {
                PortName = EnVar.GlobalSetting.MilkMachinePort,
                BaudRate = EnVar.GlobalSetting.MilkMachineBaudRate,
                Handshake = Handshake.None,
                Parity = Parity.None,
                DataBits = EnVar.GlobalSetting.MilkMachineDataBits,
                StopBits = StopBits.One,
                ReadTimeout = 1000,
        };

        serialPortMilk.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(RecieveMilk);
        serialPortMilk.Open();


//serial port for Weighing Machine
 serialPortWeight = new SerialPort
 {
              PortName = EnVar.GlobalSetting.WeightMachinePort,
                    BaudRate = EnVar.GlobalSetting.WeightMachineBaudRate,
                    Handshake = Handshake.None,
                    Parity = Parity.None,
                    DataBits = EnVar.GlobalSetting.WeightMachineDataBits,
                    StopBits = StopBits.One,
                    ReadTimeout = 300,
                    WriteTimeout = 500,
                };

                serialPortWeight.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(ReceiveWeight);
                serialPortWeight.Open();
```

I am able to read from weighing machine continuously and the value is correctly update in the application UI every second.

The problem I am facing is: 
When user presses the button on milk machine and data is sent on port, it takes 4-5 seconds until the DataReceived event is fired. If I do it in continuation, i.e., press the button again on machine, the next DataReceive event will fire after 8-10 seconds. This delay keeps building up. Another fact is that if I close the Weighing Machine port and just keep the Milk Machine port open, the DataReceived event of Milk Machine port is fired instantly.

This is what I am doing inside the ReceiveMilk delegate:

```
try
{
  machineData = serialPortMilk.ReadLine();
  serialPortMilk.DiscardInBuffer();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  return;
}

//string operations

Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
{
  //set values in UI
}}));
```

and almost similar in ReceiveWeight delegate.

I have tried different timeouts, readbuffer, thread sleep before/after reading.. but nothing resolves this issue.

Comment: can you post button event? are you using any thread.

Comment: Not using thread specifically. But I read that when we attach delegate to datareceived event, it runs on a separate thread by default. Added snippet from callback function to the question.

Comment: I am not sure, Which one is causing the issue. Check the buadrate. Try to increase that might help quick transmission. I have used multiple com ports in my application for dairy industry. I never face such delay in reading the values.

Comment: Check this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13031372/net-serialport-taking-over-0-5-seconds-to-read-byte-when-bytes-available?rq=1

Comment: A closer look revealed that port # 1 is sending data every 350 milliseconds and it is somehow keeping the thread so busy that it does not get to process the datareceived event of port # 2 when the data is actually received. To fix it for now, I am closing the serial port # 1 after receiving data and re-opening after 1 second delay so that whenever data is received on port # 2, it will get processed during the 1 sec delay when port # 1 is closed. Now this is not a recommended practice as suggested in many posts, but it is working fine as of now. I will post if I find another solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem I've seen with using the `DataReceived` event when **multiple** `SerialPort`s are involved. If you google for the problem, you'll see that it's an issue as old as time.

[Refer to this MSDN thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d5b07e74-6277-428f-b60f-3049df9d69af/c-problem-with-multiple-serialdatarecieved-event-handlers). To quote one of the responses: *"the .NET SerialPort isn't a very good component"*. Some people have reported success with tweaking the `ReceivedBytesThreshold` value. Most have to resort to polling for data, instead of the event-based method ([also here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53879072/5623232)).

Try with the threshold first, as it could be a quick win for you. Otherwise, a refactor may be required.

Answer (score 0):

I have software running upwards to 30 devices on 30 serial ports simultaneously and I don't have any issue with the `DataReceivedEvent` lagging.  I think the issue may be that you are using `machineData = serialPortMilk.ReadLine();` in which I think ReadLine is an blocking function.  That's probably causing the thread to get hung up.  I would recommend using `ReadExisting()` as it just immediately returns what's in the character buffer for the Serial Port class.

Edit:

According to MSDN:

> By default, the ReadLine method will block until a line is received. If this behavior is undesirable, set the ReadTimeout property to any non-zero value to force the ReadLine method to throw a TimeoutException if a line is not available on the port.

Read more about the `ReadLine` property here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.readline?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. However, the data being sent does contain a line break. The function does not appear to be blocking, because data is updated in UI every 350 milliseconds. I will try ReadExisting() as suggested by you and will post the results.